# Using Redis for Queues for Multiple Laravel Applications on a Single Server

Tags: laravel, redis, queue

I have a production laravel application and the staging application running on the same server. I am running redis, which I am using as my queue driver. They are obviously connected to different databases. The question is if jobs that are pushed onto the reds queue from the staging application will interfere with the production db and vice versa.

Comment: Would you consider accepting my answer below if you feel that it is most helpful?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the prefix Laravel uses for the Redis cache. By default this is `laravel`, so all keys are stored as `laravel:keyname` and Laravel takes care of the logic to add/remove this prefix when saving/getting.

You can set the prefix in `config/cache.php`. You could leave the main one as `laravel` and set your staging app prefix to `stage` or something. This will mean multiple Laravel apps can use the same Redis instance.

Comment: I know you asked this over 6 months ago, but people might Google themselves here or whatever.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did.

Comment: This is ok for Redis as cache, although what about Redis as queue driver?

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan is right. Changing the `CACHE_PREFIX` env value (which gets used here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/b8120bfb55501b2d36e93b657f51523ce6502530#diff-ef16cabd572189f548df70d3f0042c33) does not help with collisions of 2 Laravel apps both set to use Redis as queue driver and pointing to the same Redis installation on the same server. I'm still searching for a solution myself.

Comment: See @Ryan's answer if anyone's still looking for a solution. It works for me - tested using `php artisan queue:listen` and `php artisan tinker` to dispatch a test job.

Answer (score 17):

I had this same problem, and it took me hours to find the solution.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#driver-prerequisites says:

> In order to use the `redis` queue driver, you should configure a Redis
>   database connection in your `config/database.php` configuration file.

And then https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redis#predis says:

> In addition to the default `host`, `port`, `database`, and `password` server
>   configuration options, Predis supports additional [connection parameters](https://github.com/nrk/predis/wiki/Connection-Parameters) that may be defined for each of your Redis servers. To
>   utilize these additional configuration options, add them to your Redis
>   server configuration in the `config/database.php` configuration file.

Reading the "connection parameters" page, I eventually found https://github.com/nrk/predis/wiki/Client-Options, which says that 'prefix' is a supported option.

So, you can edit your `config/database.php` configuration file to have:

```
'redis' => [
        'client' => 'predis',
        'cluster' => false,
        'options'=>[
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', 'YOUR_PREFIX_HERE')
        ],
        'default' => [
            'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
    ],
```

I'm not sure if you then need to restart Redis or Supervisord.

Comment: As of Laravel 5.8 (and likely up to at least 6.4) this is the correct answer. If you're having this problem, I'd go one step further and leave the prefix within `config/cache.php` empty, and make `database.redis.options.prefix` your only entry point for a prefix string. By doing this, you do lose the `:` nicety, but you can just add in a `:` yourself (`'prefix' => 'PREFIX:'`). If you define both `cache.prefix` and the databases' `options.prefix`, your keys will double up and look like `PREFIXPREFIX:`.

Answer (score 7):

As of [Laravel 5.5.22](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/releases/tag/v5.5.22) the cache prefix is using the `APP_NAME` environment variable. You can rely on that if that's enough or alternatively you may configure the prefix by using the `CACHE_PREFIX` environment variable that is not set by default.

[image: <code>CACHE_PREFIX</code>]

If you're using Laravel Horizon to manage your queues, you can simply override the `HORIZON_PREFIX` environment variable to let Horizon differentiate between your applications running side by side.

[image: <code>HORIZON_PREFIX</code>]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default Laravel queue in .env for the Redis.

```
REDIS_QUEUE=your_app1_queuename
```

By default this is '**default**',

this used  in config/queue.php.  This will mean multiple Laravel apps can use the same Redis instance.