# Multiple Laravel Apps with a Singe Redis instance

Tags: laravel, redis, namespaces, laravel-5.6

Is it possible to run two Laravel apps on a single Redis server without key name collisions? I did not see documentation for setting a namespace or adding a cache prefix.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redis

Comment: This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50354984/470749

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, at least for those of us using `phpredis`. It seems like this not possible with the default `predis` driver.

> In addition to the default host, port, database, and password server
>   configuration options, PhpRedis supports the following additional
>   connection parameters: persistent, prefix,  read_timeout and timeout.
>   You may add any of these options to your Redis server configuration in
>   the config/database.php configuration file:

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'phpredis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
        'prefix' => 'my-app-prefix'
    ],

],
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redis#configuration

Comment: Prefix works well, but doesn't provide any isolation between the two apps. If app1 runs a slow command, app2 will be affected as well. The recommended way is to run two different processes, one for each app. You can run them on the same server if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Redis supports multiple 'databases' per server: you would just need to set 'database' => 1 in your config. However, as per [the docs](https://redis.io/commands/select) it is not recommended:

> In practical terms, Redis databases should mainly used in order to, if needed, separate different keys belonging to the same application, and not in order to use a single Redis instance for multiple unrelated applications.

So depending on your usage you're probably better off just spinning up another redis server alongside the current one.